# How to prevent milk overflow from pan?

Tags: milk, boiling

Note - To avoid duplication, I have referred the related [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5207/can-i-boil-milk-unattended-and-still-keep-the-pan-clean).

Many a time, it happens that I put milk on the stove and forget about it while doing other work. So, milk always boils over. What can be done to prevent the milk overflowing the pan?

[image]

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/5207/69382

Comment: Hi, to prevent a duplicate, it's not enough to say that you have seen the other question. You have to make it clear why you are asking something different than it. In this case, I see no diffrence in what is being asked, and it seems that the people who answer also don't see a difference - all answers would fit both questions. So I am closing and merging.